# Event.type not working as expected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following bit of code:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter taphold', 'a.button.fav.bp-secondary-action', function() {
    tb_event_type = event.type
    //run code
```

On PC, only mouseenter is triggered. On iphone only taphold is triggered. On android both mouseenter and taphold are triggered (I only want one to be triggered). To stop one of them I was going to use this code:

```
if ((event.type=="mouseenter") && (android==true)) { return false }
```

However event.type doesn't appear to work on taphold (just stops the code from running at all). How can I run the code only once on android where both events are triggered?

Thanks! :)

Comment: It is not clear from your code why it is a problem, but surely you would want something like `$(document).on('mouseenter taphold', '....', function(e) { if (android && e.type==="mouseenter") { e.preventDefault(); return;}`

Comment: It's a problem because it's a hover, which comes up and animates twice on android (one for each event type). putting in this line ```event_type=event.type ```  stops the code from running if the event type is taphold. No problem in the console. I'm stumped. EDIT: stops ANY taphold events running on any device.